# How to keep esri map state when switch the page in AngularJS site

Tags: angularjs, esri

I am using esri map(javascript) in my AngularJS site. All esri resources were downloaded in my local and using dojo.js to load esri map in page. When switching map page to another page and go back to map page again, the map was initialized. Is there any way to keep the state of map? e.g: zoom level. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, I can think of 2 options to handle this.

1. Persist the state of the map somewhere outside the map and any transition to the map route can re-create the map and use the state info to get it back to its previous state. This is what we do in Open Data (an Ember app). Map state is maintained in routable URL parameters, so the URL  http://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/CAPCOG::schools?geometry=-104.712%2C28.588%2C-90.649%2C31.909&selectedAttribute=INSTR_TYPE tells the dataset route to open the map at the bbox specified in the “geometery” parameter, to add the “CAPCOG::schools” layer, with a smart mapping generated renderer on the “INSTR_TYPE” field. As you can imagine, if you had a lot of map state to manage, that could get complicated quickly. We get away w/ that b/c we’re only tracking a few bits of state
2. Move the map to some `<div>` that is outside of the routable view area, and then add custom logic in the route to manage the map (i.e. create, hide, show, destroy, etc). That’s the general idea, but you’d have to custom tailor it depending on the workflow of your app. The benefit would be that you would not need to destroy/recreate the map over and over again. Which means you would not need to keep track of the map's state, just whether or not it should be visible on any given route and/or whether or not it has been created yet. The downside is that you're introducing a custom state flow with side effects etc that goes "against the grain" of typical Angular development. I’m not aware of any examples out there that demonstrate this kind of approach.